# How to install .NET on Linux Mint 17

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I'm having issue with installing .NET on Linux Mint 17.

I've used the steps from here:

> https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu

When I run `sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1` the following errors occurred:

```html
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-dev-1.0.1 : Depends: dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.4 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How should I fix that?
What is the proper way to install .NET and compile code in Linux? 
What IDE should I use? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding in the fix flag? Sometimes that helps with dependency issues.

`sudo apt-get -f install dotnet-dev-1.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install curl libunwind8 gettext apt-transport-https
```

then register the keys using the commands

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
```

Then you need to register the Microsoft product feed and this depends on your machine for Mint 17 its like this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-trusty-prod trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'    
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

Now you're pretty much good to install it, you should have all your dependencies so just :

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
```

You should be good to go.